# Neo4j - Cypher query returning wrong Nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

While try to query a node with auto index in cypher it returns irrelevant nodes,
As shown below i queried for node having contno='GESU5697150' but it returns some other node too.

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ start n=node:node_auto_index(contno='GESU5697150')  return n;
==> +----------------------------------------------------+
==> | n                                                  |
==> +----------------------------------------------------+
==> | Node[546290]{contno:"UACU5047693",sizetype:"40HC"} |
==> | Node[700914]{contno:"GESU5697150",sizetype:"40HC"} |
==> +----------------------------------------------------+
==> 2 rows
```

Is this cypher / Neo4j issue?!. Due this i am facing problem with fetching the record at java code

```
Ncontno = autoNodeIndex.get("contno", contno).getSingle();
```

it throws below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: More than one eleme
nt in org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex$1@211b3c6a. First element is 'Node
[546290]' and the second element is 'Node[700914]'
```

Comment: Can you perhaps share what you did to import your data?

Comment: @Michael Hunger , used below code `firstNode = null; firstNode = graphDb.createNode(); firstNode.setProperty("contno", contno); firstNode.setProperty("sizetype", sizetype); container.add(firstNode, "contno", contno); container.add(firstNode, "sizetype",sizetype);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got a temporary solution for the above problem by verifying the contno in the collection of resultset.

```
hits = container.get("contno", contno);
  for (Node n : hits) {
    if (n.getProperty("contno").toString().equalsIgnoreCase(contno)) {
           Ncontno = n;
    } 
  }
```

so Ncontno will hold the expected contno. But still looking for better/ permanent solution

Answer (score 1):

Autoindexes in Neo4j do not care about reindexing existing content when autoindexing config changes. If autoindexes were switched off while changing the contno property you'll see the described behaviour.

To fix this, you can set a property with its pre-existing value, triggering a implicit update of the auto index:

```
start n=node:node_auto_index(contno='GESU5697150') set n.contno = n.contno
```

Rerunning the original query should return just one element.

Schema indexes in Neo4j 2.0 address this inconvenient behaviour, see my [blog post on various index types](http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2013/12/indexing-in-neo4j-an-overview/) in Neo4j.

Comment: 1.`If autoindexes were switched off while changing the contno property you'll see the described behaviour` -- auto Indexing was on during the whole creation process. 2) i did this `start n=node:node_auto_index(contno='GESU5697150') set n.contno = n.contno` but still the results are same.!!

Comment: plz refer the above comment!!

Comment: are you sure that autoindexing is enabled? grab the latest startup sequence out of your messages.log using https://gist.github.com/sarmbruster/8001713 and upload it to pastebin

Comment: Hi, even tried the entire exercise again with auto_index enabled, but still the same issue occurs and then tried same with [IndexManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368579/select-a-node-by-name-in-neo4j-in-java) also but problem still exist..

Comment: pls refer the above comment and log at [message.log](http://pastebin.com/pTqwBMGw)

Comment: Can you perhaps share what you did to import your data?

Comment: @MichaelHunger , used below code `firstNode = null;`
                    `firstNode = graphDb.createNode();`
                    `firstNode.setProperty("contno", contno);`
                    `firstNode.setProperty("sizetype", sizetype);`
                    `container.add(firstNode, "contno", contno);`
                    `container.add(firstNode, "sizetype",sizetype);`