# How to get node by name in neo4j 1.9.3 by using Java API?

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j version `1.9.3`. There will be more than **10 Billion** nodes in database. 
As of now, I am using Indexing (got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368579/select-a-node-by-name-in-neo4j-in-java)) for getting nodes by the specific property (i.e name of the user etc). But it seems indexing makes slower to write to the database. 
How is it possible to use **Java API** in `neo4j 1.9.3` for querying nodes by specific property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With indexes as you said. You could also create in-graph structures (e.g. tree's or lists) to access your nodes in a structured fashion, see:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-cookbook-path-tree.html

And as in any other databases indexes add write performance impact.

Why don't you upgrade to a more recent version? Like 2.3.1 ?

Comment: I had conflict between Lucene version 5.1.0 and neo4j 2.x.y. Then, solved that problem by using uber-jar [link](https://github.com/lagodiuk/neo4j-uber-jar). Thus, I continue with version 1.9.3.

Comment: You mean using indexes with neo4j adds performance? And how is it possible to create permanent indexes, using indexes with existing neo4j database?

Comment: With schema indexes in neo4j 2.x